# Populate Android App with JSON data

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I want to build an android app for a restaurant. I want it to display the menu in several activities using listviews. One for drinks, one for meals, one for deserts, etc. The menu comes from a json file which is being parsed in a splashscreen on app start.

Now i'm wondering what's the best way to populate the listviews and activities after parsing the json:

1. Populating the listviews from the splashscreen activity?
2. Storing the menu data in files and access them on the depending activity's oncreate()…?
3. Parsing a separate json file for each activity?

What is the best way in terms of performance, simplicity and effectiveness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That would imply you have all you Acticities with their ListViews up & running when the splashscreen is starting. Probably not what you want.
2. You already said the JSON is stored in a file. You can parse that JSON in your splashscreen Activity, keep a global reference to it and let you Activities pick the part they need from that global class / JSONObject.
3. Tradeoff: Parse the complete JSON once and let all Activities retrieve the parts they need from it (this is basically 2.) at the 'risk' of parts of it never being used or split the JSON into several parts that are being loaded/parsed on demand by every Activity seperately, but having the overhead of doing file transactions in every Activity.

Either way, if the menu you're storing isn't immensely huge, the difference in performance will be minimal. 
I'd go 2., load the whole file at startup, store the data globally and let every Activity make use of it.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really answer my question. What i meant in my question was,  which of the 3 ways mentioned is the best? Although thanks a lot for your recommendation. I'll have a look at gson.

Comment: That's because the question changed ;)